# Filter rule for SMS / text messages in exchange active sync (SMS sync)

Tags: sync, exchange, email-filter, sms

Exchange server 2010 introduces SMS Sync (via exchange active sync), which works fine with my Android device and the Samsung email app. However, all text messages are synced to my exchange inbox, which is a pain. I'd like to have them filtered to a specific folder.

So far, I haven't figured out a useful filter rule for achieving that, since there seems to be no header indicating it's a text message. Has anyone managed to do that?

Note that I'm not using Outlook as an email client, so I'm specifically looking for a server-side rule.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, found out how to disable SMS syncing?

Comment: On Android, go to _Settings > Accounts and Sync > active sync account > Account settings_ and untick _SMS sync_

Answer (score 0):

I have created a rule to match the country code.

> "Apply this rule after the message arrives with +**country_code** in the sender's address
>   move it to the SMS folder
>   except with @ in the sender's address
>   stop processing more rules"

This only half works though. Whenever a service with a name sends me an SMS they obviously goes through. Outlook clearly knows that it comes from the mobile phone, so there should be some more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about a rule like this as well. But as you noted, Exchange/Outlook knows it's an SMS, so the same logic determining that should be applicable for setting up a filter.