# Disable SMS Syncing on Outlook

Tags: sms, exchange-2010

I've paired up my Samsung phone with an Outlook Exchange inbox (probably Outlook 2010), and now I've got the outstanding SMS syncing feature. Only, of course, it sucks, since my inbox get's flooded with SMS's that I already have on my phone.

After looking around the internet for quite a while for a option that would allow me to disable that kind of syncing, the only guide I got was designed for Windows Phone 6.x.

I want desperately to disable it. Anyone has any clue of how? I can't really believe that MS has forgotten to include the option.

I've already looked at [this question (Filter rule for SMS / text messages in exchange active sync (SMS sync))](https://superuser.com/questions/331469/filter-rule-for-sms-text-messages-in-exchange-active-sync-sms-sync), and while it might help me, that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On the phone, go into the email app

1. Push the menu soft key.
2. Select "settings".
3. Select your email address. DO NOT tap "General preferences", tap your actual email address.
4. Scroll to the bottom and uncheck Sync SMS

OR:

1. Go to Settings
2. Select "Microsof Exchange ActiveSync" in Accounts group
3. Select the "Settings" under Common settings group
4. Select your email address. Do NOT tap "General preferences", tap your actual email address.
5. Scroll down to the last choice: "Sync SMS", under Server settings group and uncheck it

Comment: On my Samsung Galaxy Aviator, Lionel's answer was useful, but this novice had no idea what "go into the email client" means. Here is the sequence I used. Each number is a new screen. 1. Press the "Settings" icon on the home screen 2. Press "Accounts and Sync" 3. Under "Manage Accounts", select your Outlook Exchange account 4. Under "General settings", press "Account settings" 5. Scroll almost to the bottom, and uncheck SMS sync under "Incoming settings"

Answer (score 1):

1. On the ribbon under file (Tools menu),

   [image]
2. Click Account Settings.

   [image]
3. Select the Outlook Mobile Service account that you want to remove
4. Then click Remove.

   To confirm the removal of the account
5. Click Yes